# Altering column to add sequence error in Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE C_ORDER  
( 
    OrderNumber     NUMBER(5), 
    OrderDate       DATE DEFAULT (sysdate), 
    CustomerName    VARCHAR2(100), 
    CONSTRAINT c_order_pk PRIMARY KEY (OrderNumber),
    CONSTRAINT customername_uq UNIQUE(CustomerName)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE ordernumber_seq 
 START WITH     1 
 INCREMENT BY   1 
 NOCACHE 
 NOCYCLE;

ALTER TABLE C_ORDER 
    MODIFY OrderNumber NUMBER(5) DEFAULT ordernumber_seq.NEXTVAL;
```

The code was working in livesql but when I try to execute it in Toad this error shows:

> > ALTER TABLE C_ORDER 
> >         MODIFY OrderNumber NUMBER(5) DEFAULT ordernumber_seq.NEXTVAL
> >     Error at line 1
> >     ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: Which version of oracle database are you using? It's not supported to use `seq.nextval` as default value until Oracle 12c.

Comment: I am usong Oracle 11g

Comment: You need a trigger to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Oracle 12c, but in 11.2g is not allowed yet,
 please refer to the documentation of [ALTER TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001) statement for version 11.2g:

> **DEFAULT**
>
> Use the DEFAULT clause to specify a default for a new column or a new
>   default for an existing column. Oracle Database assigns this value to
>   the column if a subsequent INSERT statement omits a value for the
>   column. If you are adding a new column to the table and specify the
>   default value, then the database inserts the default column value into
>   all rows of the table.
>
> The data type of the default value must match the data type specified
>   for the column. The column must also be large enough to hold the
>   default value.
>
> **Restrictions on Default Column Values**
>   Default column values are
>   subject to the following restrictions:
>
> A DEFAULT expression **cannot contain references to other columns, the
>   pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL**, LEVEL, and ROWNUM, or date constants
>   that are not fully specified.
>
> The expression can be of any form except a scalar subquery expression.

---

You need `BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER some_name
BEFORE INSERT ON C_ORDER
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  :NEW.OrderNumber := ordernumber_seq.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```